# why groupBy from rxjs in angular is not working?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

When i map from my object and then aply groupBy it doenst group. Let me show.

```
this.accountService.list(acc1).pipe(
      map((ac :any) => ac.list),
      groupBy(x => x.currency),
      mergeMap(group =>  group.pipe(toArray()))
    ).subscribe(data => {
      data.forEach((l: AccountDto[]) => { //para cada lista de moneda
        if (l.length != 0) {
          console.log("cuenta: " + l[0].currency);
          l.forEach(x => console.log(x));
        }
      })
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Here the results in console:

```
cuenta: Bs.
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002051210266", currency: "Bs.", amount: "2,000.06", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002051210278", currency: "Bs.", amount: "745.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002052210287", currency: "$us", amount: "800.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
```

There are two currency = 'Bs.' and one currency = '$us' but the three are in the same array.

Feel free to make questions. (Im latino please ignore my English sintaxis)

EDIT1: This is my expected output:

```
cuenta: Bs.
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002051210266", currency: "Bs.", amount: "2,000.06", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002051210278", currency: "Bs.", amount: "745.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
cuenta: $us.
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002052210287", currency: "$us", amount: "800.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
```

Comment: can you mentioned your expected output ?

Comment: `cuenta: Bs.
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002051210266", currency: "Bs.", amount: "2,000.06", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002051210278", currency: "Bs.", amount: "745.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}
cuenta: $us.
summary.component.ts:45 {numAccount: "002052210287", currency: "$us", amount: "800.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO", …}`

Comment: Yo can check below EDIT1 in the POST

Answer (score 1):

That is because groupBy groups emittions of the stream. Your only emission is the array, not the elements of the array. You simply need to stream the elements of the array. You can use `concatAll` for that.

```
const data = {
  list: [
    {numAccount: "002051210266", currency: "Bs.", amount: "2,000.06", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO"},
    {numAccount: "002051210278", currency: "Bs.", amount: "745.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO"},
    {numAccount: "002052210287", currency: "$us", amount: "800.00", typeAccount: "CA", state: "NO"},
  ]
}

of(data).pipe(
  map(ac => ac.list),
  concatAll(), // HERE
  groupBy(x => x.currency),
  mergeMap(group =>  group.pipe(toArray()))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: summary.component.ts(39,22): error TS2339: Property 'currency' does not exist on type '{}'.

Answer (score 0):

instead map use mergeMap in first line

```
 this.accountService.list(acc1).pipe(
          mergeMap((ac :any) => ac.list),
          groupBy(x => x.currency),
          mergeMap(group =>  group.pipe(toArray()))
        ).subscribe(data => {
          data.forEach((l: AccountDto[]) => { //para cada lista de moneda
            if (l.length != 0) {
              console.log("cuenta: " + l[0].currency);
              l.forEach(x => console.log(x));
            }
          })
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: summary.component.ts(39,22): error TS2339: Property 'currency' does not exist on type '{}'.
In btoch cases!